# Facing issue with Laravel once uploaded in AWS using EC2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, amazon-web-services

we have developed an application using Laravel version 5.6. It's working fine with our current VPS hosting. Now we have switched the site to AWS from VPS and site stopped working although same code working fine on our previous non-cloud server.

Issue I'm facing:
This page isn’t working
domain.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Friends, any one can given good suggestion how i can fix this issue?

Comment: Can you please check apache server logs for the 500 error?

Comment: activate laravel debug mode to see if there is any errors, also check the server log

Comment: Apache server log would be inside `/var/log/` directory. please check logs, you can find error over there for missing any required extension or other server related error.

Comment: Hi, thank you, Darshan. Let me try it

Comment: You storage, Bootstrap folders should be writetable 

sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/storage
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/bootstrap